# How do I compare the value in a list to the first value of a nested list and return the nested list results?

Tags: python, compare, nested-lists

I have the following two lists.

List 1

```
(a,b,h,g,e,t,w,x)
```

List two

```
((a,yellow),(h,green),(t,red),(w,teal))
```

I want to return the following

```
((a,yellow),(b,null),(h,green),(e,null),(t,red),(w,teal),(x,null))

for x in List_1:
     for y in list_2:
           if x == y
             print y
           else print x, "null"
```

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: `(a,b,h,g,e,t,w,x)` is a tuple `[a,b,h,g,e,t,w,x]` is a list

Comment: What happened to g in your example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
a = ('a', 'b', 'h', 'g', 'e', 't', 'w', 'x')
b = (('a', 'yellow'), ('h', 'green'), ('t', 'red'), ('w', 'teal'))
B = dict(b)
print [(x, B.get(x, 'null')) for x in a]
```

Comment: A good solution as long as you don't mind spending extra mem for the dict. Makes sense when you need to make several comparisons with list `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. The only thing you need is to form a list, not to print results outright.

If you insist on nested loops (it's a homework, right?), you need something like this:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "h", "g", "e", "t", "w", "x"]
list2 = [("a", "yellow"), ("h", "green"), ("t", "red"), ("w", "teal")]

result = [] # an empty list
for letter1 in list1:
  found_letter = False # not yet found
  for (letter2, color) in list2:
    if letter1 == letter2:
      result.append((letter2, color))
      found_letter = True # mark the fact that we found the letter with a color
  if not found_letter:
      result.append((letter1, 'null'))

print result
```

Comment: A dictionary conversion of list2 saves you from all that special case code and inner loop and state tracking.

Comment: This is a typical RAM vs CPU tradeoff (and dict conversion is efficient but still costs a little bit of CPU).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "h", "g", "e", "t", "w", "x"]
list2 = [("a", "yellow"), ("h", "green"), ("t", "red"), ("w", "teal")]
print dict(((x, "null") for x in list1), **dict(list2)).items()
```

Answer (score 0):

A short pythonic list comprehension within a list comprehension:

```
[(i, ([j[1] for j in list2 if j[0] == i] or ['null'])[0]) for i in list1]
```

A longer version:

```
def get_nested(list1, list2):
    d = dict(list2)
    for i in list1:
        yield (i, i in d and d[i] or 'null')
print tuple(get_nested(list1, list2))
```